# How to replace certain words in all DropDown List elements

Tags: jquery, replace

I have the following dropdown list:

```
 <select id="dropdown">
      <option value="AB">Alberta Standards</option>
      <option value="BC">British Columbia Standards</option>
 </select>
```

Trying to Change Standards to Curriculum without Changing anything else.

This is what I have:

```
$('#dropdown option').filter(function() { return /Standards/.text($(this).text());}).text('Curriculum');
```

But this replaces everything to Curriculum!  Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiya **working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/fppeZ/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/fppeZ/1/

Good read: http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

> The metacharacter \b is an anchor like the caret and the dollar sign.
>   It matches at a position that is called a "word boundary". This match
>   is zero-length.
>
> There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:
>
> - Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a    word character.
> - After the last character in the string, if the    last character is a    word character.
> - Between two characters in the    string, where one is a word    character and the other is not a word    character....

HOpe this helps,

**Jquery code**

```
$('#dropdown option').each(function() {

     $(this).text($(this).html().replace(/\bStandards\b/g, 'Curriculum'));
});​
```

Comment: Can this be applied for replacing a character within a string for a dropdown menu? Say a '*'?

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```
$('#dropdown option').each(function() {
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace( /Standards/gi, 'Curriculum'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#dropdown option').each(function() {
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/Standards/g, 'Curriculum'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

your filter function finds the elements which contains text 'standards' then replaces their text
instead you can use

```
$('#dropdown option').each(function(i,v){
  $(v).text().replace( /Standards/gi, 'Curriculum');
});
```

Comment: Thanks but doesn't do what I need!

Answer (score 0):

Just use `each`:

```
$("#dropdown option").each(function () {
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace("Standards", "Curriculum")​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​);
​​​​​​});
```

​